# The Unofficial Wheel of Blame

Tags: app, website

### Screenshot

[image]

### About

The chat room [Tavern on the Meta (MSO)](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/89/tavern-on-the-meta), in its early days, developed a habit of `/blame`ing someone (anyone!) whenever something relatively significant went wrong. When something really significant went wrong (the entire web cluster crashed) [one November day years ago](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/265762#265762), the perpetrator's confessional tweet was reposted by **@radp** almost immediately, followed by

> **@radp** no need to spin the wheel o' blame here...
>   **@YiJiang** I have no idea what that does.

**@YiJiang** promptly created [the first automated Wheel of Blame](http://jsfiddle.net/AYPpF/1/show/light/), which [appeared an hour and a half later](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/265832#265832). Approximately twenty-three revisions later, [this ultra-handy tool](http://jsfiddle.net/AYPpF/24/show/light/) was welded to the Tavern's description box, so as to be easily accessible when something went wrong. About fifty-eight revisions after that, [an updated version](http://jsfiddle.net/AYPpF/82/show/light/) was bolted on to replace it (to quote: *bolted on so it's secure, yet maintainable; that old weld was a pain to break*). That's where I found it when I first visited the Tavern. I personally thought it could use some improvement - storing the things-to-be-blamed in HTML seemed horribly duplicative, and there was a lot of inconsistent text too, among other things. Unwilling to "rock the boat" at such an early stage of my MSO existence by blatantly pointing this out, I went ahead and quietly forked the JSFiddle.

#### License

Released under CC-BY-SA 3.0 ("you can share it under the same license, and make stuff based on it, as long as you credit me").

#### Download

```
http://jsfiddle.net/michaelb958/vSfXT/show/
```


For past versions, add a number from the changelog before `show/`; for example,


```
http://jsfiddle.net/michaelb958/vSfXT/12/show/
```

*(**Versions 20 and 22 are special**, due to me not checking if I was logged in before hitting <kbd>Update</kbd>; delete the `michaelb958/` before attempting to access those ones.)*

#### Platform

It *should* work on Internet Explorer 10 and latest Firefox, as those are the browsers I have available to test on.

### Contact

It's just me, [@michaelb958](https://stackexchange.com/users/1048581/michaelb958?tab=accounts). To get in touch, ping me on [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) or comment on this post.

### Code

Made with and hosted by [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), using [jQuery 1.x](http://jquery.com), [cssesc](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/cssesc), and [jQuery Easing](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/).

#### Changelog

> 1. - Forked from [the official version](http://jsfiddle.net/AYPpF/82/show/light/)
>    - Moved data on things-to-be-blamed from HTML to JavaScript
>    - Upgraded to jQuery 1.9.1
>    - Changed doctype from XHTML1 to HTML5
>    - Changed subscript paragraph colour (for visibility)
> 2. - Gave C# an "image" (well, `<code>`d text really)
>    - Changed sub-paragraph colour again (for visibility)
> 3. - Fixed the sub-paragraph (it still had the old name for [Tavern on the Meta](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/89/tavern-on-the-meta), and the wrong contact username)
> 4. - Tweaked the CSS controlling the wheel
> 5. - Changed "SO Dev Team" to "SE dev team"
>    - Tweaked wheel CSS again
>    - Added another sub-paragraph with quick link to be copypasta'd
> 6. - Tweaked wheel CSS yet again
> 7. - Found a better copypasta link
>    - Changed sub-paragraph colour yet again (for visibility)
> 8. 
> 9. - Wheel items are now randomly shuffled each page load
>    - Added myself to the wheel (after all, I've now contributed)
>    - Added JavaScript to the wheel (infuriating language...)
>    - Added jQuery to the wheel (seemed legit)
>    - Added Internet Explorer to the wheel (there's lots to blame it for)
>    - Significant modifications to wheel CSS
> 10. - Finally remembered to add "Unofficial" to the title and body
> 11. - Made the "Unofficial" in the page body red
> 12. - Adjusted wheel's spinning - now guaranteed to spin further
>     - Image updates
>     - Tweaked wheel CSS yet again
> 13. 
> 14. - Fragment identifiers now lock the wheel to specific items (however, it's bugged)
> 15. - Fragment-locks are, despite my efforts, still bugged
> 16. - Added a sub-paragraph with a link to the original Wheel of Blame
> 17. - Fragment-locks work now (yay!)
>     - Removed jQuery from wheel (jQuery is the **solution**, not the problem)
>         <sup>I see you're trying to blame jQuery for a problem with SE. You should totally drop that and try jQuery.</sup>
> 18. 
> 19. - Sub-paragraph CSS tweak
> 20. - Now works properly in Firefox (I was using a Surface RT as dev machine, so could only test with IE)
>         <sup>[It's Internet Explorer's fault!](http://jsfiddle.net/michaelb958/vSfXT/show/light/#ie)</sup>
> 21. - Added exotic characters to *Spin* button
> 22. - Wheel items can now have multiple fragment-locks (however, they're b0rked again)
>     - Added the Chaos Monkey from the [unseen most-recent Official Wheel](http://jsfiddle.net/AYPpF/94/show/light/); also updated link to said
>     - Upgraded to automatically use the latest jQuery 1.x
>     - Changed sub-paragraph colour yet again (for visibility)
> 23. - Made rounded corners on wheel viewport more pronounced
> 24. 
> 25. 
> 26. - Fragment-locks are finally fixed
> 27. 
> 28. - Added caching to the wheel (it causes 120% of all bugs)
>         <sup>Caching. It's always caching...</sup>
>     - Added localisation to the wheel (at the time, it was practically the new caching)
>     - Capitalised [Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9)'s name correctly
>     - Added more exotic characters to *Spin* button
> 29. - Added [the Community bot](https://stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) to the wheel (we all know it's out to get us...)
>     - Fragment-locks are now fully case-insensitive
> 30. - Added robo-reviewers to the wheel (dragging down quality on SO since `/review` was introduced)
>     - Enhanced apostrophisation - names ending in `s` are now suffixed with `'` instead of `'s`
> 31. - Added some more blameable employees from [badp's wheel](http://jsfiddle.net/zmV5w/60/show/light/):
>
>       - [Rebecca Chernoff (rchern)](http://stackexchange.com/users/60791/rebecca-chernoff?tab=accounts)
>       - [Sam Saffron (waffles)](http://stackexchange.com/users/9321/waffles?tab=accounts)
>       - [Sklivvz](http://stackexchange.com/users/4623/sklivvz?tab=accounts)
>       - [Anna Lear](http://stackexchange.com/users/37099/anna-lear?tab=accounts)
>       - [Tim Post](http://stackexchange.com/users/20808/tim-post?tab=accounts)
>       - [Brent Ozar](http://stackexchange.com/users/13381/brent-ozar?tab=accounts)
>       - [Geoff Dalgas](http://stackexchange.com/users/2/geoff-dalgas?tab=accounts)
>     - Made copy-paste quick link better - now, just click the box to auto-select it
> 32. - Increased the spin time - with all those blameables to get through, it was going a little fast

Comment: maybe you could add the "security monkeys" from Info Security SE? http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/questions/880/the-memes-of-information-security

Comment: @TheUgly I don't think I'll be adding them at this time; this is primarily a Meta Stack Overflow tool. You are, of course, welcome to fork.