# Request for a userscript to activate the "Wheel of Blame" Easter egg in chat

Tags: discussion, chat, script-request

Note: This is not the same as [The Unofficial Wheel of Blame](https://stackapps.com/questions/4357/the-unofficial-wheel-of-blame).

The Stack Exchange chat sites have an Easter egg called "Wheel of Blame" that activates for the current user only. Right now, the only way to activate it is by [entering commands into the JavaScript console](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/220533/377214).

I'm looking for a user script that can execute the requisite commands to activate this built-in Easter egg, without having to open up the JS console and enter the commands myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here's a script that adds a button to launch those Easter eggs:

[image: New easter egg button]

Once installed, merely select the desired Easter egg from the drop-down then press the *EEgg* button.  <sup><sub>(Then weep for the poor puppy you could have petted/walked with that time.)</sub></sup>

**To install**, click [here (*Chat, Wheel of Blame and other Easter eggs* install at GitHub)](https://github.com/BrockA/SE-misc/raw/master/Stack%20Exchange%20Chat%2C%20Wheel%20of%20Blame%20and%20other%20Easter%20eggs.user.js).
(Requires a userscript engine like Tampermonkey or Violentmonkey.)

**To preview the source**, click [here (*Chat, Wheel of Blame and other Easter eggs*  preview at GitHub)](https://github.com/BrockA/SE-misc/blob/master/Stack%20Exchange%20Chat%2C%20Wheel%20of%20Blame%20and%20other%20Easter%20eggs.user.js).

---

Tested on/with Tampermonkey. Should work with other decent userscript engines...

Comment: Version 1.1 of the patch fixes it for me in Edge with SOUP running.

Comment: I filed an issue with the developer of SOUP: https://github.com/vyznev/soup/issues/35

Comment: Apparently there are [two more Easter eggs](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5115/11329): "MovieStrip" and "MTG". Can those please be added to the script? (The question there is regarding another, third Easter egg specific to Travel chat rooms; due to its nature it may not fit within this script.)

Comment: @gparyani, the three new eggs (Map, MovieStrip, MTG) already run in the appropriate chatrooms automatically.  No need to add them to the script -- which apparently no one besides us uses.